# Lua class member function calling for each other

Tags: lua, torch

I have a following Lua class:

```
-- file: myClass.lua
local myClass = {}
myClass.__index = myClass

setmetatable(myClass, {
    __call = function (cls, ...)
        return cls.new(...)
    end,
})

function myClass.new(init_size)
    local self = setmetatable({}, myClass)
    self.max_size = init_size
    return self
end

function myClass:set_max_size(x)
    self.max_size = x
    print(myClass:get_max_size()) -- <= [1]
end

function myClass:get_max_size()
    return self.max_size
end

return myClass
```

In terminal, after the following command, the output was not what I expected.

```
> myClass = require 'myClass'
> myClassObj = myClass(5)
> myClassObj:set_max_size(10) ---<== this line will print nil instead of 10 as expected.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

As `max_size` isn't implemented as a class variable but a property of an instance (or whatever lingo you might use in the context of Lua), you need

```
self:get_max_size()
```

instead of

```
myClass:get_max_size()
```